# Create a record with Typescript react app into Dataverse

Tags: typescript, dataverse

I am looking for a solution to create a record within Dataverse from a typescript app and all the information regarding authorisation etc.

I have found a nom package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamics-web-api

I need to know will this do the job and if so - any more information on the subject or has anyone done it ?

I am using but I am getting an error with this piece of code :

```
try{
    //call any function
    const responseDyn = async () => {
        await dynamicsWebApi.executeUnboundFunction('WhoAmI');
    }
    console.log(`Hello Dynamics 365! My id is: ${responseDyn.UserId}`);
}
catch (error){
    console.log(error);
```

it is saying UserId does not exist on type Promise(void) - how does it know because it hasn't got the json yet so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is a code error -- nothing to do with Dataverse. Try to wrap everything inside an async arrow function, or use then().

```
(async () => {
    const responseDyn = await dynamicsWebApi.executeUnboundFunction('WhoAmI');
    console.log(`Hello Dynamics 365! My id is: ${responseDyn.UserId}`);
})();
```

Next, it's perfectly possible to talk to Dataverse from a react app but the first challenge to overcome is authenticating to Azure & Dataverse and obtain a token to include in your web requests.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/authenticate-web-api) for an explanation about authentication being required, then [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/quick-start-register-configure-simplespa-application-msal-js) for all the detailed instructions & code samples create an Azure app then authenticate using MSAL.js (Microsoft Authentication Library).

The github library you are looking at is a 3rd-party library and not the official one. The github page [explains](https://github.com/AleksandrRogov/DynamicsWebApi#dynamicswebapi-for-nodejs) that the library doesn't handle authentication for you. Nothing wrong with that library, just pointing it out since you might prefer using using standard fetch HTTP requests first. See Dataverse [Web Api documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/perform-operations-web-api).

Finally, no authentication is required to use the web api inside Dataverse model-driven app / canvas app -- since in those cases you're already logged in.